# MappingException: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: hibernate

I would like to establish `many-to-many` relationship between objects.
I have in `Book` class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long book_id;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "UserHibernate", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id",
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private Set<User> user;
```

And in `User` class I have:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
private List<Book> books;
```

I don't have any other tables. I have `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value = "create" />` so I expect hibernate will create tables for me.

I get following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_6ipoxvx8h128sx13eysun7r00:UserHibernate [book_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (UserHibernate [user_id,book_id])
```

Could anyone help me to find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice to meet you dude. I see you are a new kid in hibernate, then listen: you have to specify in `@JoinTable` intermediate table for many-to-many relation, eg `User_BookHibernate`:

```
 @JoinTable(name = "User_BookHibernate", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id",
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
```

Hibernate will create 3 tables for you. `User_BookHibernate` will match `user_id` to `book_id`.